# Ongoing notification disappears on ics

Tags: android

In ICS,after installation ongoing notification disappears after some time, and when any other notification is called, the previous notification also appears and everything works fine. It only happens with ICS, previous versions are running perfectly. Is there anything new regarding notification in ICS?

Comment: I also noticed similar behavior in one of the apps I was working on. After inspecting the logs, it appeared that on some of the garbage collector calls the notification was being destroyed. So, it would appear that there is a bug in ICS that the garbage collector can destroy an ongoing notification perhaps arbitrarily. I never got to the bottom of the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: "I never got to the bottom of the issue, unfortunately." So, I'm not exactly sure...